# OWL: How to create a class that consists of a relation between two other classes?

Tags: rdf, owl

I would like to create the following scenario in OWL:

- Lets say there is a game wich is played by pairs of players (just like tennis doubles).
- I have the class "Player";
- I have the object property "doublesWith" that has as domain "Player" and range "Player";

Now I want to define a class called something like "Teams" that is a Collection (or something) of "Player --doublesWith--> Player".

How to do that? Is it possible?

Edit: trying to clarify it.

- I have the class "Player";
- I have the object property "doublesWith" that has as domain "Player" and range "Player";

I want to create a class that groups not just Players, but the "triple" "Player --doublesWith--> Player".

Let's say there is a class called "Double" that may wrap that triple. Then I want to create a class called "Teams" that is something like

```
<owl:Class rdf:about = "Teams">
 <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType = "Collection">
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Double"/>
  </owl:withRestrictions>
</owl:Class>
```

In other words, an instance of "Teams" is a collection of "Double".

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post what you've attempted.

Comment: Unfortunately I really don't have a clue about how to do that...

Comment: Flagging as too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @Rvo it's really not quite clear what you're asking for.  You can certainly reify the relationship, and have a *class* DoublesWith and a *property* hasPlayer so that you can say "dw42 a DoublesWith . dw42 hasPlayer player3 . dw42 hasPlayer player4."

Comment: Understood... But I would like that doublesWith still remain as an object property. I'll try to edit the question making it more clear.